# RewriteRule Not Working in .htaccess file

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to change the URL of my website to show only the ID but It seems to not work...

I don't know why.. other commands of RewriteRule work well..
Actually the .htaccess file looks like belove

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/$ article.php?articleId=$1 [L]
```

I want that it works like this:
Old_URL(to modify):
`mywebsite.it/article.php?articleId=15`  
I want something like this:`mywebsite.it/article/15`
But the URL remains the same actually: always display this: 
`mywebsite.it/article.php?articleId=15` 
Thanks in advance to every help :)

Comment: Give a proper example of a URL you want to rewrite here, and a proper explanation of what "not working" actually means as well.

Comment: I want that it works like this:

old_URL(to modify) ->https://www.mywebsite.it/article?articleId=15

I want something like this: -> https://www.mywebsite.it/article/15/

But  the URL remains the same actually:

always display this: https://www.mywebsite.it/article?articleId=15

Comment: Something like: `RewriteRule ^/?article/([0-9]+)/$ article.php?articleId=$1 [L]` ? (assuming .htaccess is at the docroot)

Comment: Yes, It is in docroot

but Something like: RewriteRule ^/?article/([0-9]+)/$ article.php?articleId=$1 [L]
doesn't work

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't hide it in the comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An internal rewrite will *never* change the URL visible in the browser. You are probably looking for an external redirection. Or better the combination of both:

```
RewriteEngine On
# externally redirect old URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)articleId=(\d+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?article/?$ /article/%1 [R=301,L]
# internally rewrite new URL
RewriteRule ^/?article/(\d+)/?$ /article.php?articleId=$1 [END]
```

Those rules are meant to be implemented on top level. Best in the actual http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that then a distributed configuration file will work (".htaccess") when located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, but support for that needs to be enabled.

It is a good idea to start out using a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once you are happy with how things work. That prevents caching issues on the client side.